# Getting list from current web in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

i have a application page, which i am using to get list items from current web using java-script.

i only want 1 fields value for all list-items, i have field's GUID, please guide ?

**field is a custom field**

Answer (score 0):

On your query you need to specify which field do you want back. For example:

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(
    collListItem, 
    'Include(Id, DisplayName, HasUniqueRoleAssignments)'
);
```

the last line of code specify that you want back only the: Id, DisplayName, and HaUniqueRoleAssignments values.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: i donot know how to check it as well

Comment: type the name of your custom field inside the Include brackets

Comment: internal name, static name or display name

Comment: internal name...

Comment: it should be the internal name but you can always test it

Comment: it's funny because this guys doing thousand of question and then leave that without credits